# Difference between using Constraint or not when adding a primary key to a table

Tags: sql

I have executed both querys A and B and they are doing exactly the same, so, what is the difference between A and B?

A:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD CONSTRAINT "my_primary_key" PRIMARY KEY ("Name_of_column");
```

B:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PRIMARY KEY ("Name_of_column");
```

Answer (score 1):

Both statements are creating the same constraint, but statement A is choosing a custom name, whereas statement B is letting the DBMS choose the name automatically.

A custom name is useful if you later want to alter or drop the constraint, since you don't have to look up its name, or rely on the DBMS having a good naming convention.

For example, with statement A, you can reliably run this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT "my_primary_key"
```

With statement B, that won't find the constraint.

Comment: Why sometimes when I add the primary key with a custom name, for some columns it is okay, but for other columns the following error appears: `could not create unique index "my_primary_key"`

Comment: A custom name can also give more informative error messages.